# mySql get date for every other weekday

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query returns all the TUESDAYS between start and end dates. What I also need then is to return every other TUESDAY in this case.

```
select * from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) DATES from
 (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where DATES between '2018-05-21' and '2018-08-31'
and dayname(DATES) in ('TUESDAY');
```

DATES has all the dates that are TUESDAY. What I need now is how to extract every other TUESDAY. For some reason this one escapes me.

Comment: What's this got to do with MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Include `t0` in the subquery and then add a `mod` expression to the `where`:

```
where DATES between '2018-05-21' and '2018-08-31' and t0 mod 2 = 1
```

Note that this will arbitrarily choose the first or second Tuesday in the period for starting the count (your question is not clear if that is ok).

There is a actually a pretty easy way to get the counting right:

```
where DATES between '2018-05-21' and '2018-08-31' and 
      floor(datediff(dates, '2018-05-21') / 7) mod 2 = 0
```

This counts by weeks after the first date and only returns dates from every other week.

Comment: The first "day" is always the start date. So what I need is a result that has "day" in two weeks, and two weeks after that, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

change your where clause to

```
where DATES between '2018-05-21' and '2018-08-31'
and dayname(DATES) in ('TUESDAY')
and (date_format(DATES,'%U')%2 = 0);
```

that date_format() function will give you the week of the year 00 to 53 and then do a modulo test against 2. Whenever it is '0' it will be even week number. Whenever it is '1' it will be an 'odd' week number.

Comment: This worked thanks.I had the idea, I just could not figure how to implement.